# Embed Google Map into HTML page based on GPS coordinates

Tags: php, google-maps

I have a PHP photo gallery that reads the GPS coordinates from images.  I'd like to modify it to use the coordinates and include a google map on the photo page.  Is there a simple way to display a google map on an HTML page by supplying just this pair of information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The following are a few examples that you may help you getting started:

---

### Using the [Google Maps API v2](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false" 
           type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body onunload="GUnload()">
   <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
      map.setCenter(new GLatLng(51.49, -0.12), 8);
   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

You simply need to change the latitude and longitude in the `GMap2.setCenter()` method. The last paramater is the zoom level.

---

### Using the [Google Maps API v3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" 
           src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</head> 
<body>
   <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var myOptions = {
         zoom: 8,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.49, -0.12),
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

When using version 3 of the Maps API, you would need to pass your parameters as options to the `google.maps.Map()` constructor. The above example should be self explanatory.

---

### Using the [Static Map API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/):

```
<img src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.49,-0.12&zoom=8&size=400x300&sensor=false" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;" />
```

The [Static Map API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/), as [luca suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517736/embed-google-map-into-html-page-based-on-gps-coordinates/2517785#2517785) might be a very good idea.

Simply pass the the latitude and longitude paramaters in an image tag, as in the example above. It would display the map below, directly rendered from Google:

[image: Using the Static Maps API]

---

Comment: The static maps api is deprecated, and no longer works.

Comment: Maps Static API is alive and well, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/overview

Answer (score 4):

use static google map you have to supply just some other addition info

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.477222,0&zoom=14&size=400x400&sensor=false

it only show an image of the map

here is a link to the API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro

there is a lot of other options if needed

Comment: API link is Broken

Comment: The static maps api is deprecated, and no longer works.

Comment: link updated  , but StaticMap doesn't seems deprecated  ... where do you read that ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using PHP, you could also use the [PHP Google Map API class](http://code.google.com/p/php-google-map-api), which has also just been updated to use V3 of the Google Maps JS APIs.