# Embedding Google Maps with variable location in XHTML

Tags: google-maps, xhtml-1.0-strict

I have a form getting parameters (method=GET, so the parameters are in the query string), and I have an Object with an embedded Google map. I want to make the embedded map dynamic, so that it will reflect the parameters (especially ll parameter for position). There are related questions with answers on how to do it with [php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2517736/1801588) and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11014092/1801588), but is there any way to do it without scripting?
Is it possible in XHTML 1.0 Strict?

Plus, what should be the "target" syntax in the form? Neither "" nor the URL of current page does work, and different page just sends me away, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the form and the object(iframe with the map?) are located on the same page you may send the form directly to the iframe, in that case it would be possible to have a dynamic map without any scripting.

But however, when you use POST the parameters are not within the QUERY_STRING.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question; answer the new question and it will be accepted.

Comment: When XHTML strict is required my suggestion will not work, because you'll need the target-attribute for the form, but this attribute isn't valid in XHTML strict